# Opencv extra module undefined symbol error

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, opencv3.0

I have downloaded opencv 3.0.0 and opencv-contrib. I need to use xfeatures2d extra module from opencv-contrib. I am able to get the opencv framework and its libs. But not able to get xfeatures2d lib. First ;

```
~/Desktop/opencv-3.0.0/ (building below commands in this dir)
```

1- I am running the cmake command

```
$cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/dicle/Desktop/opencv-3.0.0/xfeatures2d /Users/dicle/Desktop/opencv-3.0.0/

$make
```

After typing this 2 commands i am only getting opencv 3 base modules not extra ones.. And only base libs.

I am planning to use this extra module like that btw.. 1- Import the opencv3 framework without extra modules and then create a extra-modules folders and put xfeatures2d module in it and call this folder(#include ) in my code giving path of extra module's headers but i am having this errors. I thought that maybe the reason can be related with extra module's lib. If you can help me i would be appreacite. Thank you.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create(int, int, double, double, double)", referenced from:
  AnchorBasedValidation::validate(Anchor, cv::Mat, cv::Rect_<int>, cv::Point_<float>) in IDSmart(AnchorBasedValidation.o)
"cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double, int, int, bool, bool)", referenced from:
  KeypointsExtractor::ComputeDescriptor(cv::Mat const&, std::__1::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::__1::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >, std::__1::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::__1::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) in IDSmart(KeypointsExtractor.o)
  KeypointsExtractor::ExtractKeypoint(cv::Mat const&, std::__1::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::__1::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, std::__1::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::__1::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, std::__1::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::__1::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > > const&) in IDSmart(KeypointsExtractor.o)
  KeypointsExtractor::ExtractClusterHistogram(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat, std::__1::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::__1::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >) in IDSmart(KeypointsExtractor.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I am not sure but shouldn't that be 
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/dicle/Desktop/opencv_contrib/modules